# Docmosis pdf conversion returns a converted but empty template

Tags: java, docmosis

I am using Docmosis to generate pdf reports.  A new report is returning a pdf version of the template supplied, but it is completely blank. I have confirmed that the data is being sent to Docmosis. The xml being sent is in the same form as the other reports, which is successfully rendered. The xml also contains the correct elements in the correct order for this to render correctly.
What else can I check? Have anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone finds this and wonders what the solution was :
In short - spelling mistake.
There was a miscommunication in the team and the template that was submitted was not the same one I was testing against. The casing of the fields were different ans that resulting in the blank document.